# How to complete workflow task

Tags: workflow

I have been working on a review process which uses InfoPath custom form published to SP and workflow to create tasks and assign them to reviewers. 
All above works well however what I cannot figure out is, how to complete the associated workflow task by change of field in my original form.

My workflow waits for the task completion before moving on, which is a normal behavior and I'm cool with that. I would like to simplify it for reviewers where their approval (field change in the form) automatically completes the associated task.
Current behavior is that they will approve within the form (field change) and then have to jump out to Task to complete the associated task.

Is there a way of archiving the desired result with SPD workflow?

In a nutshell I would like to set "completion" in workflow associated task when a value changes in my list from Pending to Approved. I cannot find a way to target associated task in my workflow to make this happen.

Below shows my dev form and associated task.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some further information.
The screenshots of the form is from my dev site as mentioned in above reply. I explored the item change action but I didn't really find it adequate for my purposes. What happens in my actual form is that I have 4 dynamic reviewers in a parallel block. Each reviewer has to approve before the workflow continues to the next phase. The Task is allocated to each of the reviewers within the block and pauses until that action is completed.

I'm not entirely convinced if I'm not pushing the boundaries of what SP can deliver however the intent is use the form (Item) as record post review/approval. This means that I need to have all basis for forming an approval contained in it. The item itself holds various content ranging from text to attachments and links.
As mentioned above this actually works as is however I feel it would be more intuitive for users if an approval within the form would complete the associated task.

Actual form - Content section(from IP Designer)

[image]

Actual form - Review section(from IP Designer)

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to have the approval in 2 places? Why not having the approval just in the tasks list and that's it and removing it from the form? Or keep it in the form and remove the task action from the workflow? Why using both ways?

Comment: Hi Mohamed and thanks for suggestion. The reason I'm using a task is because it has an elegant way of addressing reminders for overdue and provides me a wait function until the content of the form is actually reviewed and approved. The screenshot I provided are for a test form/workflow I created in dev site so it doesn't demonstrate the complexity behind my actual form.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention above. The actual tracked approval is expected once in the form itself. However because of the default task behavior the workflow will be paused until that task is completed. The alternative is to write up the workflow so it emulates what a task does but I'm tying to save myself time by investigating if there is a way to complete a task from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the form actions ? it will be much convinient to answer if we can see your form. Else i would suggest you to start the workflow when an item gets modified(This can be enabled easily if you have SharePoint Designer installed which is a free tool).

Comment: Thanks for reply  Arvinda. I added some further information above.